# How to implement IndexDB in IOS

Tags: ios, html, cordova, indexeddb, polyfills

I am developing a mobile application using phonegap, Initially I have developed using WEBSQL but now I m planning to move it on INDEXDB. The problem is it does not have direct support on IOS , so on doing much R&D I came to know using **IndexedDB Polyfil**  we can implement it on IOS too

http://blog.nparashuram.com/2012/10/indexeddb-example-on-cordova-phonegap.html
http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/

Can some please help me how to implement this as there are not enough documentation for this and I cannot figure out a any other solution / api except this

**I have tested this on safari 5.1.7**

Below is my code and Error Image

```
var request1 = indexedDB.open(dbName, 5);
request1.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    db = request1.result;
    var transaction = db.transaction(["AcceptedOrders"], "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("AcceptedOrders");
    for (var i in data) {

        var request = objectStore.add(data[i]);
        request.onsuccess = function (event) {

            //  alert("am again inserted")
            // event.target.result == customerData[i].ssn;
        };
    }

};
request1.onerror = function (evt) {
    alert("IndexedDB error: " + evt.target.errorCode);
};
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJh0E.png)

Answer (score 0):

## One blind guess

Maybe your `dbName` contains illegal characters for WebSQL database names. The polyfill doesn't translate your database names in any kind. So if you create a database called `my-test`, it would try to create a WebSQL database with the name `my-test`. This name is acceptable for an IndexedDB database, but in WebSQL you'll get in trouble because of the `-` character. So your database name has to match both, the IndexedDB **and** the WebSQL name conventions.

## ... otherwise use the debugger

You could set a break point onto your `alert(...);` line and use the debugger to look inside the `evt` object. This way you may get either more information about the error itself or more information to share with us.

To do so, enable the development menu in the Safari advanced settings, hit `F10` and go to `Developer > Start` debugging JavaScript (something like that, my Safari is in a different language). Now open then "Scripts" tab in the developer window, select your script and set the break point by clicking on the line number. Reload the page and it should stop right in your error callback, where you can inspect the `evt` object.

If this doesn't help, you could get the non-minified version of the polyfill and try set some breakpoints around their `open` function to find the origin of this error.

Comment: In the WebSQL standard it notes that any string is a valid DB name. Implementation wise though it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could try my open source library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home. It works on iOS and Android.